# Django Gunicorn ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi

Tags: django, gunicorn, django-settings

I have created a Django application but now have plans to use some asynchronous (real-time) functionality in some areas of the site. After doing some research I think I should use `gevent-socketio` and therefore it is required I switch the application server to `Gunicorn`.

I have fallen at the first hurdle of deploying `Gunicorn`, I have installed with the command `sudo apt-get install gunicorn` and try to run my application with `gunicorn project.wsgi:application` but it fails and produces the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 473, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 100, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 115, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 33, in load
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 362, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/home/alex/django_projects/fantasymatchday_1/fantasymatchday_1/wsgi.py", line 13, in <module>
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
2014-11-20 17:31:45 [6605] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 6605)
2014-11-20 17:31:45 [6600] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2014-11-20 17:31:45 [6600] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

Can anybody give me a clue to what I need to do from here?

**I am using python 3.4.0 and Django 1.6**

Answer (score 3):

You have to install `django` and `gunicorn` in the same environment.
If you use `virtualenv` make sure you have both in the same virtual environment.